# How to save input data before page postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql

Currently, I have an asp TextBox and Button that allow the user to search for an item in a large list. The search function works by taking the textbox text, querying a table for the rest of the data, and creating a new row in a table with the data.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="itemsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button Text="Add Item" ID="itemsearchbutton" runat="server" OnClick="AddItem"/>
```

The data that comes back from the table is stored in tds within a table. However, because the page refreshes after the codebehind, it resets all non-asp fields. I tried making a table of asp TextBoxes, but I guess that's not allowed as it's a server side field, not client side. Is there any way to retain the table data before the page refreshes?

Comment: Tables cells aren't form fields so they aren't posted at all, whether you're using ASP.NET controls or not. What you should be doing is saving the data somewhere (e.g. a database) when it's first added and then populating that table from this data source on each page load.

Comment: Seems you are unaware of [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx), [Caching](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/caching) and [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: @AntP Would saving the table in JSON work? I could read through the table, read and save it, and then fill the table on refresh.

Comment: @teabos Any form of persistence will work so, as long as you can serialize, save, load and deserialize your data to and from JSON then yes, it'll work fine. Whether it's a good idea depends on how scalable this needs to be.